# ajax data insert problem with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been trying to insert data into the database through CodeIgniter Controller. I have made a validation process and receiving validation error through response in ajax. But It seems that when in the form all the fields are filled and after that if I click on any input field the data is inserted without even clicking the save or submit button in the form.

[image]

So, if I press Name field, Color field, or Price field the data is inserted without pressing the "Save Car" button.

**My Controller: CarModel.php **

```
<?php
class CarModel extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('car_model/list.php');
    }
    public function showCreateForm()
    {
        $html = $this->load->view('car_model/create', '', true);
        $response['html'] = $html;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    public function saveModel()
    {
        $this->load->model('Car_model');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('color', 'Color', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            //save enteries to DB
            $formArray = array();
            $formArray['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $formArray['color'] = $this->input->post('color');
            $formArray['transmission'] = $this->input->post('transmission');
            $formArray['price'] = $this->input->post('price');
            $formArray['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $this->Car_model->create($formArray);
            $response['status'] = 1;
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 0;
            $response['name'] = strip_tags(form_error('name'));
            $response['color'] = strip_tags(form_error('color'));
            $response['price'] = strip_tags(form_error('price'));
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

**My Model: Car_model.php**

```
<?php

class Car_model extends CI_Model {
    public function create($formArray){
        $this->db->insert('car_models',$formArray);
    }
}
```

The ajax code in the **list.php** file. The code is given below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->


    <title>Ajax Crud</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>
                Ajax CodeIgniter CRUD
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Car Models</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right"><a href="javascript:void();" class="btn btn-primary text-right" onclick="showModel()">Create</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Transmission</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Created Date</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="createCar" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create Model</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div id="response"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function showModel() {
            $("#createCar").modal("show");
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('CarModel/showCreateForm'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#response").html(response["html"]);
                }
            })
        }
        $("body").on("click", "#createCarModel", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('CarModel/saveModel'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {

                    if (response['status'] == 0) {
                        if (response["name"] != "") {
                            $(".nameError").html(response["name"]).addClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                            $("#name").addClass('is-invalid');
                        } else {
                            $(".nameError").html("").removeClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                            $("#name").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        }

                        if (response["color"] != "") {
                            $(".colorError").html(response["color"]).addClass('invalid-feedback  d-block');
                            $("#color").addClass('is-invalid');
                        } else {
                            $(".colorError").html("").removeClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                            $("#color").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        }

                        if (response["price"] != "") {
                            $(".priceError").html(response["price"]).addClass('invalid-feedback  d-block');
                            $("#price").addClass('is-invalid');
                        } else {
                            $(".priceError").html("").removeClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                            $("#price").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(".nameError").html("").removeClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                        $("#name").removeClass('is-invalid');

                        $(".colorError").html("").removeClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                        $("#color").removeClass('is-invalid');

                        $(".priceError").html("").removeClass('invalid-feedback d-block');
                        $("#price").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help me fix it. Thank you.

Comment: $("body").on("click", "#createCarModel", function(e)      Check the selector "createCarModel" doesn't exists

Comment: It's because you have set click event on whole form. When validation fails then nothing happend, response= 0 and you have validation messages, but when form is valid every click on it creates new record in database. Try to be more precise and set "validation event" on input fields and "save event" on save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. The problem was occurring because I set the whole form as an event listener for the insert operation. I needed to use `submit` instead of `click` in the
line `$("body").on("click", "#createCarModel", function(e) {`. So, I have changed it to `$("body").on("submit", "#createCarModel", function(e) {`. Then the problem stopped happening.

Thanks to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try Changing your onclick selector to your submit button id.

Comment: Your answer is almost right. If I do that then there causes some validation problem. I have found why the issue is occurring. I have changed the following line `$("body").on("click", "#createCarModel", function(e) {` to  `$("body").on("submit", "#createCarModel", function(e) {`. Then the problem stopped happening. I was selecting the whole form for event listening. I could mark your answer as the right one but it might lead others in a bit wrong direction. BUT thank you, for you, I was able to find my mistake.